# Is there a way to use QUILoader without a project/resource file?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-creator

I used QT Creator to generate a .ui file for my Python project.
To be clear, I am not not using qtcreator to manage my entire project, I just use it as a .ui editor.

So in qtcreator, I added icons by file name, not by referencing a resource catalog, and they show fine in qtcreator.

However, they do not show up when loading the file in Python as follows, using PySide 5.15.2:

```
loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
ui_file = QtCore.QFile(ui_path)
ui_file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
form = loader.load(ui_file)
ui_file.close()
```

Looking in the XML generated by qtcreator, it looks like this:

```
     ...
       <property name="icon">
        <iconset>
         <normaloff>../../resources/icons/list-add.svg</normaloff>../../resources/icons/list-add.svg</iconset>
       </property>
      </widget>
     ...
```

Any way to run this with the icons showing up without using a .qrc file?
I am trying to avoid introducing a build step for my application/UI.

Comment: The path is (or was) relative to the ui file. What else were you expecting?

Comment: I don't understand. Why would the relative path be a problem? It is correct, in relation to the location of the .ui file.

Comment: You are right, the relative path is the cause. The loader does not take into consideration the location of the .ui file, and interprets the path as relative to a working directory. The icons load fine when changing the loader working directory to the .ui file, using `loader.setWorkingDirectory()`

Comment: Why not answer your own question?